# I'm trying to animate my text, but i need to see the node list on console and it doesnt show me

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have used terminal and run debug with node.js and typed node app.js but shows something like this "ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object. (c:\Users\Desktop\file\app.js:1:14)"

Here is my code in app.js

```
const logo = document.querySelectorAll('#logo path');
console.log(logo);
```

I have tried opening launch.json and type this

```
"runtimeVersion": "default"
```

yet it still didn't work. Please help me.

Comment: You are running your code in node.js. node.js doesn't have a `document` object. The `document` object is implemented in browser clients.

Comment: Also, even if `document` were available, you are using `document.querySelectorAll('#logo path');`, which means you are looking for ALL `path` elements (which is not a valid element in HTML) that are children of an element with an `id` of `logo` and then trying to log the entire node list, rather than trying to access a specific element within the node list.

Comment: @ScottMarcus so how do i fix it

Comment: You simply can't access browser objects when your JavaScript isn't running in a browser. If you need to work with web page elements, have your JavaScript included within the web page (or referenced by the page).